# Including HTML page dynamically gives page not found error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, web

I am trying to include an HTML page inside a jsp page at run time. Which HTML page will be included what will be decided at run time. When i include the HTML page using following code :

```
<jsp:include page="${HTMLFILEPATH}"></jsp:include>
```

The above expression is evaluated correct but HTML file is not included. Browser can not find the file at that path. Although file is present at this path. Here is the directory structure:

WEB-INF
  - JSP
     - Reports
       - htmlReport.html
     - myJsp.jsp

This is the error i get Error 403: SRVE0190E: File not found: /WEB-INF/jsp/reports/htmlReport.html

However if i use following, this works fine:

```
<c:when test="${path=='reports/htmlReport.html'}">
<%@ include file="reports/htmlReport.html" %>
</c:when>
```

I am uisng RAD 8.0.2, WAS7.0 , Spring MVC 3.0+

Comment: What is `HTMLFILEPATH`? How it is being set? Looks like the problem lies in it, or in the evaluation of it.....

Comment: @SayemAhmed: HTMLFILEPATH is actually the same "path" variable and its coming from controller.

Answer (score 1):

There could be two possibelities:

1. Problem with `HTMLFILEPATH` variable: Just print the value of the variable just above `jsp:include` and see whether it contains the correct value or not.
2. The `jsp:include` tag is getting rendered before and the `$HTMLFILEPATH` variable is not resolved. Instead either try using a Java scriptlet
    `<jsp:include page="<%=htmlFilePath%>" />`

Alternatively you can use `RequestDispatcher` (I am 100% sure it will work ;-) )

```
RequestDispatcher reqDisp = request.getRequestDispatcher(htmlFilePath);
reqDisp.include(request, response);
```

Comment: Thannks for your response, I added
    <%
    String reportPath = request.getParameter("path"); 
    System.out.println(reportPath);
    RequestDispatcher reqDisp =      request.getRequestDispatcher(reportPath);
 System.out.println("Request dispatcher = "+reqDisp);
 reqDisp.include(request, response);
  %>

but gave me same error as 
File not found: /WEB-INF/jsp/reports/reportName.html , although reports is lying there and this path is correct.